# How to Prepare dataset for customized NER

Tags: json, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-datasets, label-studio

I am trying to do a fine tuned NER using Hugging Face models and auto Train. My problem is in preprocessing data. I have text data that i annotated with label studio, but the resultant json file is not good for the training. The form required is IOB, but i have simple annotations on the text. what procedure should i follow to prepare data in the correct form?

I have tried some notebooks, but all returned me the same result. I am new in this world and i'm trying to understand how it works.